# Video poster without poster attribute (mobile browsers)

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, mobile, html5-video

I am using `video` HTML tag. So far, if I am **NOT** specifying any `poster`, how one will be selected? Does it depend on video file format? Does it depend on video content (first frame etc)? Does it depend on a mobile browser version etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've only ever used MP4 files with the video tag and each time I've not specified a poster image. It has picked up the first frame by default.

I know this information doesn't have any concrete evidence for you and may not help but thought I would share my experience.

Comment: to my experience, it was not always the case; if it always happens with your pages, I wonder what does the spec say (if either)

Comment: I've had a quick search on the web but I can't find anything in the spec that says what happens when no poster image is set. What I did find was this `"You should use the poster attribute because you don’t want the user to see nothing."` So this might imply sometimes it doesn't always sample the video (maybe depending on the file type) or it might just mean if there's a blank black frame it would appear there's nothing there.

Comment: Coming back to this... I looked at one of my videos without a poster image set on an iPhone, and it just showed a black image (which the first frame was not back). Adding a poster image then worked as expected.