# How do videos display a pre-play image without the poster tag?

Tags: video, html5-video

Is there a way to display pre-play images on a video without using the poster attribute in ? I've seen examples where the video displays a preplay image without the poster attribute, and am curious how it is done.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/vanhong/pd3Lteys/

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://player.progressionstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/ogg"> 
</video>
```

When I add a video without poster, I've been getting black screen.

My client is still creating their videos, so if it's a setting added to the native file during the video editing process, I have the chance to have them do this now before giving to me to upload.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448797/video-poster-without-poster-attribute-mobile-browsers) suggests that some browsers may be picking up the first frame by default, but this is not happening for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39231763/2813224

Comment: What are you trying to achieve... **(1)** Have some `<image>` tag that when clicked becomes a `<video>` tag?... Or **(2)** Have some `<video>` tag showing first frame only until the play button is clicked? With added specifics, you may get a faster answer to your problem.

Comment: @VC. Goal is (2). Using the poster attribute to video adds both to my workflow (creating an image from the video) and media storage space. I was curious how the video in my example displayed a pre-play image with no poster attribute.

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne. This snippet is *exactly* what I needed. `<video width="300" height="150">
   <source src="testvideo.mp4#t=0.1" type="video/mp4" />
</video>`